# Erro "E2034 Cannot convert 'TByteDynArray *' to 'TByteDynArray'"

Tags: c++, c++-builder

Preciso realizar uma integração com Sistema Horus (Saúde), utilizando C++ Builder. Já importei o `.cpp` do web service de Homologação disponibilizado para meu projeto. Estou com problemas nos métodos utilizados para envio dos dados, onde o mesmo espera um `ByteDynArray`. Tentei converter meu XML conforme um exemplo encontrado, mas não está dando certo. Segue código:

```
    TMemoryStream *memStream;
    TByteDynArray *myByteArray = new TByteDynArray();

    XMLHorus->SaveToStream(memStream);
    myByteArray->set_length(memStream->Size);

    if(memStream->Size > 0)
        Move(memStream->Memory, myByteArray, memStream->Size);


    RecebeDadosWS *integracao = GetRecebeDadosWS(true, "http://189.28.128.37/horus-ws-basico/RecebeDadosWS?wsdl", HTTPRIO1);
    integracao->recebeDados(myByteArray);`
```

Porém, ele emite :

> E2034 Cannot convert 'TByteDynArray *' to 'TByteDynArray'
>
> E2342 Type mismatch in parameter 'source' (wanted 'const
>   TByteDynArray', got 'TByteDynArray *')

Método do WebService:

`virtual horus_ws_resposta* recebeDados(const TByteDynArray source) = 0;`

Caso alguém já tenha feito essa integração, seria ainda melhor.

Comment: O que a tag *rstudio* está fazendo nesta pergunta?

Comment: Título editado: O problema não é com o webservice é a conversão das variáveis.

Answer (score 2):

Simples: nos dois casos você está esquecendo de dereferenciar o ponteiro. Você tem que passar o tipo `TByteDynArray`, porém está passando `TByteDynArray*`. No caso você não está nem usando-lhe como um ponteiro, então seria melhor que você o declarasse como variável normal ao menos que estejas usando um garbage-collector.

Outra coisa: é melhor que tenhas implementado `horus_ws_resposta* recebeDados(const TByteDynArray )` pois parece que estás tentando chamar uma função virtual pura.